# R data.table, non-equal join column selection

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data tables. One holds time series data and one holds time range of interest.

```
dt1 = data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), length.out = 4, by = 1), B = c(1,2,3,4), C = c(10, 20, 30, 40))
dt1
         date B  C
1: 2000-01-01 1 10
2: 2000-01-02 2 20
3: 2000-01-03 3 30
4: 2000-01-04 4 40
dt2 = data.table(dateFrom = as.Date('2000-01-02'), dateTo = as.Date('2000-01-03'), id = 4, name='first')
dt2
     dateFrom     dateTo id  name
1: 2000-01-02 2000-01-03  4 first
```

Now I do non-equal join on 2 columns, with no specification on return columns. I get no "date" column, but has dateFrom and dateTo. Values in dateFrom and dateTo are changed to be "date"

```
dt2[dt1, on = .(dateFrom <= date, dateTo >= date), nomatch = 0] 
     dateFrom     dateTo id  name B  C
1: 2000-01-02 2000-01-02  4 first 2 20
2: 2000-01-03 2000-01-03  4 first 3 30
```

I can get date column by explicitly asking for it

```
dt2[dt1, on = .(dateFrom <= date, dateTo >= date), nomatch = 0, .(date)] 
date
1: 2000-01-02
2: 2000-01-03
```

But I can't explicitly ask for `dateFrom`! Even though I get `dateFrom` when I don't specify columns

```
dt2[dt1, on = .(dateFrom <= date, dateTo >= date), nomatch = 0, .(date, dateFrom)] 
Error in `[.data.table`(dt2, dt1, on = .(dateFrom <= date, dateTo >= date),  : 
                          column(s) not found: dateFrom
```

Strangely, no error if non-equal join is only on one column

```
dt2[dt1, on = .(dateFrom <= date), .(date, dateFrom)]
         date   dateFrom
1: 2000-01-01 2000-01-01
2: 2000-01-02 2000-01-02
3: 2000-01-03 2000-01-03
4: 2000-01-04 2000-01-04
```

So how can I get all columns in `dt1` and `dt2` back, with `dateFrom` and `dateTo` in `dt2` not changed to use `date` in `dt1`? (Suppose both data tables have many columns that can't be typed out by hand. So somehow use `colnames(dt1)` would be great)